# Почему не парсит html страницу?

Tags: python, парсер

Осваиваю Python и библиотеку Beautiful Soup.
Хочу спарсить горячие предложения авиакомпании. Но в выводе не вижу текста, страница неправильно парсится. Помогите пожалуйста. Почему так ?
Делаю так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

URL = 'https://s7.ru'
HEADERS = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36','accept':'*/*'}

r = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(html)
for el in html.select('.special-offers__item'):
    title = el.select('.special-offers__to')
    print(title[0].text)
```

В итоге получаю ответ из скриптов, текста там нет. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Информация подгружается после `HTML` средствами `JavaScript`. Вам нужно либо исполнить `JavaScript` (например, с помощью `Selenium`), либо отправить необходимые запросы на сервер. Смотрите `F12 -> Network`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Информация подгружается после `HTML` средствами `JavaScript`, поэтому предлагаю вариант через `selenium`.

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/891a0b95b7b72d11e324efda0fc03545d36aed9a/html_parsing/www_s7_ru.py#L30):

```
import time
import traceback

# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

URL = 'https://www.s7.ru/'

# Чтобы окно с браузером не появлялось
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(URL)
    print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

    # Заметил, что без дополнительного ожидания у <from_el> не весь текст
    time.sleep(10)

    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.special-offers__item'):
        to_el = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.special-offers__to')
        from_el = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.special-offers__from')
        price_el = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.special-offers__price')

        print(f'{to_el.text:15} | {from_el.text} | {price_el.text}')

    """
    Новосибирск     | из Магнитогорска, туда и обратно | от 12 200 ₽
    Москва          | из Магнитогорска, туда и обратно | от 18 681 ₽
    Казань          | из Магнитогорска, туда и обратно | Проверить цену
    Красноярск      | из Магнитогорска, туда и обратно | Проверить цену
    Мирный          | из Магнитогорска, туда и обратно | Проверить цену
    Норильск        | из Магнитогорска, туда и обратно | Проверить цену
    """

except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

finally:
    driver.quit()
```